# Not recognized res folder in build types

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this structure:

[image]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrt1u.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrt1u.png

With gradle:

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
           //release stuff
        }

        debug {
            //debug stuff
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        pro {
            dimension "version"

        }
        lite {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".lite"
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

       debug {

           applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
           debuggable true
           signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

I have buildTypes release and debug (I need those for using server testing environment) and 2 Flavors, for Pro user and Lite users.
Everything is working fine and as expected, but I encountered some problem then trying to add different menu folder for release buildType and noticed that some res folder not recognized by the IDE as res folder. For example proDebug folder is with stripes icon recognized as res, but liteDebug are not, why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, it depends on the current selected Build Variant in the IDE